# PyPotrace pip Install Error on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pip, jupyter-notebook, potrace

I am trying to install potrace in my jupyter notebook virtual env but I am running into this error code. I have looked around for any known fixes on jupyter notebook but I can't find any, does anyone know how to fix this?

As per the first comment: I reinstalled pkg-config (via brew) and re ran the program which unfortunately did not fix the issue.

**ERROR CODE:**

```
pip install pypotrace

Collecting pypotrace
  Using cached pypotrace-0.2.tar.gz (26 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/user-c-cRme8X/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/c0/fx27s5mn44d8wj3trxnn_0940000gn/T/pip-install-d3s_0svw/pypotrace/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/c0/fx27s5mn44d8wj3trxnn_0940000gn/T/pip-install-d3s_0svw/pypotrace/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/c0/fx27s5mn44d8wj3trxnn_0940000gn/T/pip-install-d3s_0svw/pypotrace/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/c0/fx27s5mn44d8wj3trxnn_0940000gn/T/pip-install-d3s_0svw/pypotrace/
    Complete output (25 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/c0/fx27s5mn44d8wj3trxnn_0940000gn/T/pip-install-d3s_0svw/pypotrace/setup.py", line 4, in <module>
        setup()
      File "/private/var/folders/c0/fx27s5mn44d8wj3trxnn_0940000gn/T/pip-install-d3s_0svw/pypotrace/cysetuptools.py", line 149, in setup
        parsed_setup_cfg = parse_setup_cfg(fp, cythonize=cythonize)
      File "/private/var/folders/c0/fx27s5mn44d8wj3trxnn_0940000gn/T/pip-install-d3s_0svw/pypotrace/cysetuptools.py", line 222, in parse_setup_cfg
        return _expand_cython_modules(config, cythonize, pkg_config, base_dir)
      File "/private/var/folders/c0/fx27s5mn44d8wj3trxnn_0940000gn/T/pip-install-d3s_0svw/pypotrace/cysetuptools.py", line 230, in _expand_cython_modules
        module_dict = _expand_one_cython_module(config, section, cythonize,
      File "/private/var/folders/c0/fx27s5mn44d8wj3trxnn_0940000gn/T/pip-install-d3s_0svw/pypotrace/cysetuptools.py", line 239, in _expand_one_cython_module
        _expand_pkg_config_pkgs(config, section, pkg_config)
      File "/private/var/folders/c0/fx27s5mn44d8wj3trxnn_0940000gn/T/pip-install-d3s_0svw/pypotrace/cysetuptools.py", line 299, in _expand_pkg_config_pkgs
        extra_compile_args = pkg_config(pkg_names, '--cflags', env)
      File "/private/var/folders/c0/fx27s5mn44d8wj3trxnn_0940000gn/T/pip-install-d3s_0svw/pypotrace/cysetuptools.py", line 308, in _run_pkg_config
        return subprocess.check_output(['pkg-config', command] + pkg_names,
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
        return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 489, in run
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
        self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pkg-config'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 0):

Your error says that its missing `pkg-config` package.
Try installing it using : `sudo apt install -y pkg-config` (linux) or `brew install pkg-config` (MacOS)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I am up to date on pkg-config, I tried reinstalling pkg-config and rerunning the pip install. Unfortunately that did not fix the issue. Thanks again for your input.